# Как правильно писать в документе "договорный объем" или "договорной объем"?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите пожалуйста правильное написание словосочетания "договорной объем" или "договорный"? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В документе - договОрный объем. ДоговорнОй - разговорное, как и дОговор. Иногда употребляют как профессионализм типа осУжденный, но это не норма, в документе должна быть норма.